# Como renomear uma constraint no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Criei uma constraint `primary key` na minha tabela da seguinte maneira:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_user_type PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Mas agora preciso renomeá-la para:

```
CONSTRAINT PK_type PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

Com base nisso, tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

**1 -** Como faço para renomear uma `constraint` do tipo `primary key`?

**2 -** O processo para realizar a renomeação de uma constraint do tipo `foreign key` seria da mesma forma?

**3 -** No título me referi ao banco `MySQl` pois é o qual estou utilizando atualmente, mas o processo de renomeação seria o mesmo para outros tipos de banco? Como por exemplo `oracle` e `Microsoft Sql server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível renomear uma `CONSTRAINT`, mas você pode excluir e criar uma nova:

```
ALTER TABLE report_course 
    DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_report_course` PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Em relação aos outros bancos de dados, **provavelmente** a maioria permite excluir e criar de novo e a sintaxe deve ser quase igual (se não for igual), talvez algum também tenha suporte a renomeação

[Fonte SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188011/how-do-i-rename-a-foreign-key-in-mysql)